# Call to undefined method Database::prepare() oop pdo

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I have a constructor in my users class:

```
            public function __construct($pdo)
            {
                $this->pdo = $pdo;
            }
```

And that's how I usually run it:

Index.php:

```
include("config.php");
$users = new Users($pdo);
```

But I don't want to do it this way, I wanted to have a separated class for database connection

created database.class.php

```
class Database
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        try
        {
            $pdo = new PDO('mysql:host='.MYSQL_HOST.';dbname=driptone', MYSQL_USER, MYSQL_PASSWORD);
            $pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
            echo 'connected';
        }
        catch(PDOException $e)
        {
            echo $e->getMessage();
        }
    }
}
```

and now I used it like this:

```
$users = new Users(new Database());
```

I get this error:

```
connected
Fatal error: Call to undefined method Database::prepare() in C:\xampp\htdocs\drip\class\users.class.php on line 75
```

I also tried a static, same problem.

Why is it happening? How can I fix it? And is it secure from Injections/XSS attacks?

```
            /**
            * Public Method Register
            *
            * Registers the user to the system, checking for errors.
            * If error was found, it will throw new exception.
            *
            * @parm username The username the user posted.
            * @parm password The password the user posted.
            * @parm repassword The validated password the user posted.
            * @parm email The email the user posted.
            * @parm reemail The validated email the user posted.
            * @parm day The day the user posted (for date of birth).
            * @parm month The month the user posted (for date of birth).
            * @parm year The year the user posted (for date of birth).
            *
            * @return Return true means everything is correct, register successfully.
            **/

            public function register($username, $password, $repassword, $email, $reemail, $day, $month, $year)
            {
                    global $pdo;

                    // Check if passwords matching.
                    if ($password != $repassword)
                    {
                            throw new exception ("Passwords does not match.");
                    }
                    // Check if emails matching.
                    else if ($email != $reemail)
                    {
                            throw new exception ("Emails does not match.");
                    }

                    // The main insert query
                    $this->insert = $this->pdo->prepare
                    ("
                            INSERT INTO users
                            (user_name, user_password, user_email, user_birth)
                            VALUES
                            (:username, :password, :email, :birth)
                    ");

                    //Query to check if username is taken.
                    $this->user = $this->pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM users WHERE user_name = :name");
                    $this->user->execute(array(":name" => $username));

                    //Query to check if email is taken.
                    $this->email = $this->pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM users WHERE user_email = :email");
                    $this->email->execute(array(":email" => $email));                      

                    // Checking if username is taken using the query.
                    if ($this->user->rowCount())
                    {
                            throw new exception ("Username already in use");
                    }
                    // Checking if email is taken using the query.                 
                    else if ($this->email->rowCount())
                    {
                            throw new exception ("Email is already in use");
                    }
                    // Checking if birth of date is valid.
                    else if ($day > 31 || $month > 12 || $year > date('Y') || $year < 1925)
                    {
                            throw new exception ("Invalid Birth of date");
                    }
                    // Checking if password is more than 5 characters long.
                    else if (strlen($password) < 5)
                    {
                            throw new exception ("Password is too short");
                    }
                    else
                    {
                            // Everything is fine, insert data.

                            $this->insert->execute(array
                            (
                                    ":username" => $username,
                                    ":password" => $password,
                                    ":email" => $email,
                                    ":birth" => $day.'/'.$month.'/'.$year
                            ));

                            //Send verification

                            $this->sendVerification($username, $email);
                            //Finished processing, return true.
                            return true;
                    }
            }
```

Comment: Could you also add the relevant code from your Users class and the Database class?

Comment: Possible duplicate? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16343388/call-to-a-member-function-prepare-whats-wrong-with-this-oop?rq=1

Comment: Added the function where it happens.

Comment: The error says all you need to know. There is nothing more to add to it. Also you're not making any queries in the code shown. So making no queries is pretty safe in my book ;-)

Comment: @mike Not really, this quesiton is completely different. I am looking to do the same method, just using a class or a static. Not just the variable.

Comment: Your problem is variable scope. (You are not assigning a property in your DB constructor, using a global reference elsewhere, and accessing a non-existant PDO instance lastly). Refrain from making everything overly OOP unless you mastered visualizing variable resolution and nested objects.